# use the following solution, to solve $y''=\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(3\pi x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

given that $y''=-\lambda y$, $y(0)=0$, $y(1)=0$ and $\phi_{n}(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin(n\pi x)$, $\lambda=n^{2}\pi^{2}$.

solve:
$y''=\sin(2\pi x)-\sin(3\pi x)$, $y(0)=0$, $y(1)=0$.

The main idea of this question is using the **data** to solve it, and not other super-techniques.

what I thought is taking
$$
\phi_{2}=\sqrt{2}\sin(2\pi x)\\\phi_{3}=\sqrt{2}\sin(3\pi x)\\\frac{\frac{\phi_{2}}{4}-\frac{\phi_{3}}{9}}{\pi^{2}\sqrt{(2)}}
$$
which should also be a solution, as it is a linear combination of solutions therefore according to Sturm–Liouville theory, must be also a solution.

Am I correct?

Comment: @LutzLehmann fixed thanks

Comment: Now it looks good (check that it is identical to your task, esp. in the second problem). If you feel like it, you could put even more emphasis on the expansion of the right side in eigenfunctions before using linear algebra to solve the DE.

Comment: Can you clarify "you could put even more emphasis on the expansion of the right side in eigenfunctions before using linear algebra to solve the DE"? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Write the equation as $$-\sum \lambda_nc_n\phi_n(x)=\frac1{\sqrt2}(\phi_2(x)-\phi_3(x))$$ for $y_n=\sum c_n\phi_n$ and then compare coefficients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sturm-Liouville theory states that for each $\lambda_{n}$ there is an eigenfunction $\phi_{n}(x)$ that is unique up to an arbitrary constant. Then $\phi_{n}''(x)=-\lambda_{n}\phi_{n}(x)$ where $\lambda_{n}=n^{2}\pi^{2}$ for $n\in\mathbb N.$

For the case $n=2$ we have $\phi_{2}''(x)=-4\pi^{2}\phi_{2}(x)$ and for the case $n=3$ we have $\phi_{3}''(x)=-9\pi^{2}\phi_{3}(x)$. We want to find a solution $y(x)=A\phi_{2}(x)+B\phi_{3}(x)$ to the given problem so substituting we have $y''(x)=A\phi_{2}''(x)+B\phi_{3}''(x)=-4A\pi^{2}\phi_{2}(x)-9B\pi^{2}\phi_{3}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_{2}(x)-\phi_{3}(x)).$

Then comparing sides gives $A=-\frac{1}{4\pi^{2}\sqrt{2}}$ and $B=\frac{1}{9\pi^{2}\sqrt{2}}$, so the required solution is $y(x)=-\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{4\pi^{2}}+\frac{\sin(3\pi x)}{9\pi^{2}}.$